# How do I create the Quick Launch FlyOut menu without Sharepoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

The below link describes how to create a flyout menu for Quick Launch.  Unfortunately where I work SharePoint designer is blocked.  Do I really need SP designer.  Is it possible to copy the v4 file some other way and then make the changes...

Also I assume if I edit this file it will impact my parent site and subsites ?

[FlyOut Menu using SP Designer](http://www.manageprojectsonsharepoint.com/blog/2011/04/26/enable-flyout-menus-on-the-quick-launch/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all; It is a MasterPage and applied anywhere you told Sites (and System Pages) to use this MasterPage.

No need to copy the file,

MasterPages are in: `[site url]/_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx`
(*you do need Design rights on the Site!*)

- You can [open the Library with Explorer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2629108)
- (you might need to change the extension to .txt)
- Then use any text editor you like to edit/save the files
- (set the correct file extension again)

You could also download; and upload a new version of the file.

**These files are under Publishing control; Editors can see the changes, you need to publish a Major version for all**

Its a whole lot of work without Designer and you are most likely to mess up things at one stage...
Tell Dilbert in the IT department it is going to be his fault..